# Adding clickeventlistener to all children of a particular class using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am making a card like this:
[image]

The expected behaviour is that when I click any of the rating circles, their color should change to grey for which I have a class defined in my css that I toggle using js code.

The codepen for my solution is [this](https://codepen.io/amansavaria1402/pen/dymadwr). Using the js code that I have written, whenever I click any of the ratings, the last one turns grey all the time.

This is my current code:

```
// getting the objects
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('button');
const ratingsParent = document.querySelector('.ratings');

console.log(ratingsParent.children);

// sanity check
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Clicked');
})

for (var r of ratingsParent.children) {
    r.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        r.classList.toggle('clicked');
    })
}
```

But when I change `r.ClassList.toggle` to `evt.target.ClassList.toggle`, it shows the expected behaviour. Im extremely new to JS and just starting to learn frontend dev so Im unable to figure out the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

`var` has different behaviour than `let` and `const` when declared in a loop header – it only creates a single variable for the entire loop, which all closures share. You clearly have support for `let` and `const`, so you should *literally never* use `var`. (Maybe there’s a linting rule you can enable?)

```
for (const r of ratingsParent.children) {
    r.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        r.classList.toggle('clicked');
    });
}
```

There’s also the option of attaching a single listener to the parent and letting events bubble up, note.

```
ratingsParent.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.parentNode === ratingsParent) {
        e.target.classList.toggle('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use `document.querySelectorAll(".ratings")` to get all the elements containig this particualr class. Then you can simply loop through the array with a `forEach` loop like this: 
```
ratingsParent.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
    elem.classList.toggle("clicked");
  });
})
```

Comment: @AmanSavaria: Although actually, you should use `<input type="radio">` for a lot of built-in accessibility (keyboard support, screen reader support, etc.) – see https://codepen.io/rnoh/pen/YzaBazK (still needs focus states though)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment Ry, Im very new to the world of frontend and have started just a few weeks ago so I didn't know this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ali. Yeah I thought of that approach but before that I wanted to know whats conceptually wrong with my approach.